# else condition is not executing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nested

in this following else if ,the last else condtion is not executing ?

Please help me

```
if (Flag==1)
{
    ...
}
else if ([totalBooksId containsObject:currentbook])
{
    ...
}
else if (![totalBooksId containsObject:currentbook])
 {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

All variable have some values but still else is not executing.
the above else statement is not executing at all? Please help me

Comment: It seems your problem may be in `else if([totalBooksId containsObject:currentbook]){}` and `else if(![totalBooksId containsObject:currentbook]) { }`. Either of the two will always hit, thus the last else will never hit.

Comment: lets set the Breakpoints and see on your end whats going on ?

Comment: Your second `else if` statement captures everything that won't be captured by the first `else if`, since it is an inverse of it, hence the final `else` will never be reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is will work

```
  if(Flag==1){
        if([OwnList containsObject:currentbook]){
            if(fileExists) {
                [self renameReadButton];
            }else if(!fileExists){
                [self renameDownloadButton];
            }
            [self renameLendButton];
        }


    }

        else if([totalBooksId containsObject:currentbook]){


                    //Checking bought books
                    if([OwnList containsObject:currentbook]){

                        if(fileExists){
                            [self renameReadButton];
                        }else {
                          [self renameDownloadButton];
                        }

            } else{

        [self renameBuyButton];

        }                      
    }
    else if(![totalBooksId containsObject:currentbook]) {  


                    if([freeList containsObject:currentbook]){
                        if(fileExists){                                
                            [self renameReadButton];
                        }else{                    

                            [self renameDownloadButton];
                        }                               

            }  else{

        [self renameBuyButton];

    }                      

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the last else on an else-if block is not hit it usually means either of these:

1. One of the conditions in the initial if clause or the following else-if clauses was true
2. One of the evaluated conditions altered the program path (exception, stack corruption, etc.)
3. The code of the entire if-else block was never reached

In your case it seems to be the first case, because one of the else if conditions is the inverse of another.

Either ([totalBooksId containsObject:currentbook]) is true, or !([totalBooksId containsObject:currentbook]) is true. To hit the final else, both of them must be false.

Answer (score 0):

You have three statement

```
else if([totalBooksId containsObject:currentbook]) // first
{

} 
else if(![totalBooksId containsObject:currentbook]) // second
{

}
else { [self renameBuyButton]; }  // last
```

Last statement is not executed because first and second catch all possible situations.

First catch `[totalBooksId containsObject:currentbook] == true` , second cath `[totalBooksId containsObject:currentbook] == false` and there is no third possibility.